# Java hibernate error ConfigurationException

Tags: java, hibernate

I am studying Java Hibernate but get the errors listed below. Could you please help me to find my error? Thanks.

```
Apr 11, 2017 11:32:46 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final}
Apr 11, 2017 11:32:46 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at testhibernate.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:20)
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
    at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:244)
    at testhibernate.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:17)
```

Comment: Where is the file `hibernate.cfg.xml` located in your Project?

Comment: suppose you add hibernate.cfg.xml file to `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF` folder and refer it in your dispatcher servlet.

Comment: @ Jens The hibernate.cfg.xml file is located in src/testhibernate/ where testhibernate is the pakage

Comment: try to put it directly inside src.. outside testhibernate.

Comment: Thanks. There still is an error in creating the sessionFactory object: Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error accessing stax stream

Answer (score 1):

Put the xml file in src->main->resources folder. And don't forget to mark the resources folder as resource from IDE.